# Find all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

$n+1$ divides $n^3+2$.

Notice that $n+1$ divides $n^3+1$ so using linear properties of divisibility we have : $(n+1) \mid (n^3+2-n^3-1)$. So $(n+1)\mid 1$. So $n=0,-2$ are the only possibility.

Are there an other methods ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why do you want other method? This is the standerd method.

Comment: Asking for another method is a perfectly legitimate question. There's more than one way to skin a cat, and there's probably no place where that's more than true than in mathematics. But overmore, each different way to skin a cat can reveal different connections or hint at different generalizations. For example, why would anyone ask for a different proof of Cauchy-Schwarz when they have a particular tried-and-true method in front of them? We now know this question only squelches ingenuity.

Answer (score 2):

The systematic method is the Euclidean algorithm, which in this case has only one step:
$$x^3 + 2 = (x^2 - x + 1)(x + 1) + 1$$

Answer (score 2):

$n+1|n^3+2\implies  n+1|(n^3+1)+1 \implies n+1|1\implies n+1=\pm1\implies n=-2,0$

Answer (score 2):

One way to see things clearly is to let $n+1=m$, so you are asking for $m$'s such that $m$ divides $(m-1)^3+2=(m^3-3m^2+3m-1)+2=m^3-3m^2+3m+1$.  This implies $m$ divides $1$, so $m$ can only be $\pm1$, and thus $n=m-1$ can only be $0$ or $-2$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is written mostly because I believe that you really want to know are there any other methods (no matter how they look like) , and this is a method that is highly impractical and tedious but it is a method, although I really do not know will it lead to an answerable answer.

We have $(n+1) | (n^3+2)$, that is we have $n^3+2=k(n+1)$ for some integer $k$. From this we obtain $n^3-kn+(2-k)=0$.

Insert values of coefficients of this polynomial into formula for solutions of cubic equation.

This will give a relatively complicated expression that looks like it can be by cubing and squaring turned into a polynomial.

Then that polynomial can be investigated to see for which $n$´s it can have an integer solution.